# AngularJS loading JSON files slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I have alot of pages that are relatively the same so I'm trying to load the pages with AngularJS and JSON files in order to cut down on the amount of html I have to write. Here is my code right now:

html:

```
<a class="btn home-link one" ng-click="caseindex.number=(1)" ng-href="#/case_study/" ></a>
<a class="btn home-link two" ng-click="caseindex.number=(2)" ng-href="#/case_study/" ></a>
```

JS:

```
.controller('CaseCtrl', function($scope, $http ,caseindex, passString, resourceCache) {
    $scope.caseindex = caseindex;
      var case_select = $http({method:"GET", url:'json/case'+ caseindex.number +'.json', cache:resourceCache})
           .then(function(res){
              $scope.case_select = res.data;
                console.log(res);   

            });
})
 .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/case_study/', {
    controller : 'CaseCtrl',
     // activetab: 'apps',
      templateUrl : './case_study.html'
    }
    }
```

Loaded pages html:

```
<div ng-repeat="case in case_select | filter:'equipmentCs'" class="case-header">
    <img  ng-src="{{case.header}}"/>
</div>
<h1>Customer Profile</h1>
<div class="cs-profile">
    <ul>
      <li bindonce ng-repeat="case in case_select| filter:'custprof'"><span>{{case.profTitle}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&raquo;</span> {{case.prof}}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <h2>Situation</h2>
<div class="cs-situationCs">
    <ul>
      <li bindonce bo-text="case.sitCs"  ng-repeat="case in case_select | filter:'situationCs'"></li>
    </ul>
```

case1.json:

```
[{"category":"cat","catTitle":"equipmentCs", "header":"images/cs_header_prod@2x.png"},
{"listType":"custprof", "profTitle":"Customer", "prof":"Commercial Developer"},
 {"listType":"custprof", "profTitle":"Company", "prof":"Heavy Construction"},
 {"listType":"custprof", "profTitle":"Location", "prof":"Southwestern United States"},
 {"listType":"situationCs","sitCs":"Customer working to increase productivity"},
 {"listType":"situationCs", "sitCs":"Looking to add two scrapers to fleet"},
 {"listType":"situationCs","sitCs":"Uncertain about technology as a  means to boost productivity"},
 {"imageType":"csSitImage", "csImage":"images/customer_stories/Situation.png"},
 {"listType":"actionCs", "act":"dealer proactively integrates scrapers with Grade Control, single GPS and sequence assist."},
 {"listType":"actionCs", "act":"Customer receives 40 hours of hands-on job site training."},
 {"imageType":"csActImage", "csImage":"images/customer_stories/Action.jpg"},
 {"quoteType":"resultsQuote", "quote":"This technology is not just an add-on-it is truly the lifeblood of the machine","author":"Person Southwest"},
 {"listType":"csResults","resTitle":"Productivity increase:", "res":"up to 30%"},
 {"listType":"csResults","resTitle":"Site safety:", "res":"operators can be more aware of what’s going on around them, and safety has increased"},
 {"listType":"csResults","resTitle":"Purchasing more systems for greater gains", "res":""}]
```

It works but my problem right now is that it's loading some of the pages very slowly, I assume it is because it is trying to fetch and parse all the JSON on every load and slowing it down.

I tried using [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) to speed things up, and also tried caching the JSON so it would load faster, but its still loading some of the pages pretty slowly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The javscript code excerpt you posted is a bit limited, I think it's hard to establish context to the HTML you have. Where does this JS excerpt reside and when/how does it get called.

Comment: Perhaps you could combine all your data into a single JSON file and request that instead? Instead of requesting `json/case###.json`, create a single `json/cases.json` which identifies each object by `case_number`.

Comment: Just updated the JS with more context, also each JSON file contains a good amount of content, so although that's an option I rather keep it more organized in seperate files since it would be alot of JSON for a single file to contain. Also why would a single JSON file make loading times faster?

Comment: Are you retrieving lots of data? Have you verified that it is the JSON load that is causing the issue?  Or could it be the rendering of the data?  Can you provide a runnable sample?

Comment: It might be hard for me to add a working sample right now, but I did add a sample of one of the JSON files above.

Comment: Could use the HTML5 User Timing API to benchmark (www.w3.org/TR/user-timing/) to figure out if the JSON request is your problem or the filters and data binding are

Comment: Looking at those filters compared to your JSON data, by just using the String the filter has to search every value of every object to find matches. It seems like you could improve that by making it lookup those matches only on a specific key of the object, as in {"listType": "custprof"}

Comment: so instead of {{listType.custprof}} Id change it to {"listType":"custprof"}?   
or are you recommending to change the JSON's format?

Comment: Where is there {{listType.custprof}}? I can't verify the exact syntax at the moment but I meant something like replacing 'case in case_select| filter:'custprof'' with 'case in case_select | filter:{'listType': 'custprof'}'. I'm getting this from ng docs for filter, under expression: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Ahh sorry, I was referring to when the syntax looks like this {{case.profTitle}} within the tags. But you mean to change the syntax within the filter itself.